# How to check if an objects relation is empty?

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseObject current;
...
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Primary");
    try{
        if(current == null){
            System.out.println("current is NULL");                   //prints properly
            System.out.println("Initial query: " + query.count());   //prints 'Initial Query: 90'
            query.whereDoesNotExist("Parent4");
            System.out.println("Test1");                             //prints properly
            System.out.println("Query Count: " + query.count());     //seems to cause nullpointer
            List<ParseObject> list = query.find();
            System.out.println("Test2");
            for(ParseObject p: list){
                listItems.add((String)p.get("Title")); //listItems used to populate listview when listview is generated

...(closing brackets,else statement, exception catching, rest of program)
```

I'm trying to search my parse database entitled "Primary" for all of the items that have an empty relation in the field "Parent4"(Relation) and display them into my list of strings (listItems) that are added to the listView when it is created. I know that two of the objects in my database don't have any relation, so I want the titles of those two objects to be displayed. I had a somewhat working version of this before that worked fine, except that I was checking the title of each object in the list instead of the object itself which caused problems later on in my program when two objects had the same title, which is something that should be acceptable in my program.

Any idea why the line "query.whereDoesNotExist("Parent4");" seems to be causing a null pointer exception when I want the count of the query to be printed? Or any idea how I can deal with this instead?

Here's the log:

```
12-06 18:20:50.030: I/Process(2469): Sending signal. PID: 2469 SIG: 9
12-06 18:20:57.740: I/System.out(2517): current is NULL
12-06 18:20:58.159: I/System.out(2517): Initial query: 92
12-06 18:20:58.159: I/System.out(2517): Test1
12-06 18:20:58.378: D/AndroidRuntime(2517): Shutting down VM
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517): Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 2517
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.parse.ParseQuery$18.then(ParseQuery.java:1014)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.parse.ParseQuery$18.then(ParseQuery.java:1011)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:307)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:304)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:350)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:344)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:561)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:595)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:489)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: E/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at bolts.Task$9.ru
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: exClass=java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: exMsg=Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: file=ParseQuery.java
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: class=com.parse.ParseQuery$18
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: method=then line=1014
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.parse.ParseQuery$18.then(ParseQuery.java:1014)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.parse.ParseQuery$18.then(ParseQuery.java:1011)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:307)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:304)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:350)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:344)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:561)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:595)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:489)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517):  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecuto
12-06 18:20:58.379: D/Error(2517): ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 13252
```

Comment: Question: Could you clarify what you mean by "query.whereDoesNotExist("Parent4");" seems to be causing a null pointer exception when I want the count of the query to be printed? "On which line is the exception being called? The `whereDoesNotExist` or the `count()` after

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not sure. My eclipse log doesn't seem say 12-06 18:09:41.636: D/AndroidRuntime(2121): --------- beginning of crash
12-06 18:09:41.659: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 18:09:41.659: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 2121
12-06 18:09:41.659: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Could you post the error log too?

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
You can do that via next approach

```
ParseQuery<RelationParse> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Primary");
ParseQuery<TestParse> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Primary");
query.whereDoesNotMatchQuery("Parent4", innerQuery);
List<TestParse> listWithEmptyRelations = query.find();
```

Comment: Parent4 is in the Primary class and it refers to the primary class, so I don't think that'll work. Is there still an easy solution like this?

Comment: Then you need to use "Primary" at inner query, too.

Comment: What are RelationParse and TestParse?